# Horizontal scrolling container?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement a horizontal scrolling container in between my fixed nav links on top and on the bottom, [as shown here](https://cmrngetty5.xhbtr.com/). With the same amount of padding in between the images and the same padding on the outside of the first and last image as there is on the nav links.

Any ideas?

```
    <div class="container">

            <div class="content-wrapper">

              <div class="child">
                <img src="img/26Kibera5-superJumbo.jpg">
              </div>

              <div class="child">
                <img src="img/26Kibera5-superJumbo.jpg">
              </div>

              <div class="child">
                <img src="img/26Kibera5-superJumbo.jpg">
              </div>

              <div class="child">
                <img src="img/26Kibera5-superJumbo.jpg">
              </div>

              <div class="child">
                <img src="img/26Kibera5-superJumbo.jpg">
              </div>

            </div>

          </div>

</body>

</html>
```

```
.container {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    width: 75vh;
    height: 75vw;

    overflow: scroll;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: center calc(50vh);
  }

.child {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    margin: 10em auto;
    padding: 10em;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;

    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
```

I expect the images to horizontally scroll, centered between the nav links.

Comment: @Saravana not sure I understand?

Comment: you want exactly as per your reference website?

Comment: yeah. I made that website on a portfolio host called xhbtr and I'm trying to code it myself

Comment: Ok good. I will try to exactly as per your sample website

Answer (score 0):

You can use carousel,slider instead and can stop auto sliding also.

Answer (score 0):

As per your sample website I have completed the design. You can scroll the `content-wrapper` class horizontally. Optionally I have added the `width:400px` for image later you can remove or change the value.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}

.menu {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 25px;
}

.menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
    margin: 0;
}

.m-auto {
    margin-left: auto;
}

.child {
    margin-right: 16px;
    padding: 15px 0;
}

.content-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 30px 0;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

img {
    height: 400px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="m-auto">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="child">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x500">
        </div>
        <div class="child">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x500">
        </div>
        <div class="child">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x500">
        </div>
        <div class="child">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x500">
        </div>
        <div class="child">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x500">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="m-auto">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there a way I can get the nav links to stay in the corners of the page with maybe 25px of padding on each side, and then have the image container be larger between them?